# More efficient way for modifying values across multiple lines with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

After learning the basics of data transformation in R, I'm practising now on a a dataset. I do have four variables with the same values and I want to modify the numeric values into character strings. I found the function case_when() on this website and applied that to each column, but I would really like to do that faster.

The data looks like that:

```
 climate_change air_quality water_polution trash
            <dbl>       <dbl>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1              3           2              2     1
 2              3           3              3     3
 3             NA          NA             NA    NA
 4             NA          NA             NA    NA
 5              1           1              1     1
 6              2           1              4     2
 7              2           3              3     2
 8             NA          NA             NA    NA
 9              3           3              2     2
10             NA          NA             NA    NA
```

And I used this code:

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(climate_change = case_when(
    climate_change %in% c(1) ~ "A very serious problem",
    climate_change %in% c(2) ~ "A somewhat serious problem",
    climate_change %in% c(3) ~ "Not a very serious problem",
    climate_change %in% c(4) ~ "Not at all a serious problem"),
    air_quality = case_when(
      air_quality %in% c(1) ~ "A very serious problem",
      air_quality %in% c(2) ~ "A somewhat serious problem",
      air_quality %in% c(3) ~ "Not a very serious problem",
      air_quality %in% c(4) ~ "Not at all a serious problem"),
    water_polution = case_when(
      water_polution %in% c(1) ~ "A very serious problem",
      water_polution %in% c(2) ~ "A somewhat serious problem",
      water_polution %in% c(3) ~ "Not a very serious problem",
      water_polution %in% c(4) ~ "Not at all a serious problem"),
    trash = case_when(
      trash %in% c(1) ~ "A very serious problem",
      trash %in% c(2) ~ "A somewhat serious problem",
      trash %in% c(3) ~ "Not a very serious problem",
      trash %in% c(4) ~ "Not at all a serious problem"))
```

In addition to the four values (1-4) these variables have two types of missing values (88, 99). I have left out the missing values in the case_when() function as these seem to be coded into NA automatically. But are there any downsides in not specifically code these values into NA?

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the same function to multiple columns you can use `across` in new `dplyr`.

If there is only one value for one number you can use `recode`

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  mutate(across(climate_change:trash, 
                #use everything() if you want to do it for all the columns
                ~recode(., `1` = "A very serious problem",
                           `2` = "A somewhat serious problem",
                           `3` = "Not a very serious problem",
                           `4` = "Not at all a serious problem")))
```

Similarly, using `case_when` :

```
dataset %>%
   mutate(across(climate_change:trash, 
                ~case_when(. == 1 ~ "A very serious problem",
                           . == 2 ~ "A somewhat serious problem",
                           . == 3 ~ "Not a very serious problem",
                           . == 4 ~"Not at all a serious problem")))
```

---

In old `dplyr` you can use `mutate_at` :

```
dataset %>%
   mutate_at(vars(climate_change:trash), ~case_when....
                                          #same code
   #Use mutate_all if you want to do it for all the columns.
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with a `named` `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- setNames(c("A very serious problem","A somewhat serious problem",
     "Not a very serious problem", "Not at all a serious problem"), 1:4)
dataset %>%
   mutate(across(climate_change:trash, ~ v1[as.character(.x)]))
#             climate_change                air_quality               water_polution                      trash
#1  Not a very serious problem A somewhat serious problem   A somewhat serious problem     A very serious problem
#2  Not a very serious problem Not a very serious problem   Not a very serious problem Not a very serious problem
#3                        <NA>                       <NA>                         <NA>                       <NA>
#4                        <NA>                       <NA>                         <NA>                       <NA>
#5      A very serious problem     A very serious problem       A very serious problem     A very serious problem
#6  A somewhat serious problem     A very serious problem Not at all a serious problem A somewhat serious problem
#7  A somewhat serious problem Not a very serious problem   Not a very serious problem A somewhat serious problem
#8                        <NA>                       <NA>                         <NA>                       <NA>
#9  Not a very serious problem Not a very serious problem   A somewhat serious problem A somewhat serious problem
#10                       <NA>                       <NA>                         <NA>                       <NA>
```