# R: Named vector to reclassify many classes data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I need to reclassify my values in `data.table`, e.g. create a new column. I have over 30 classes to reclassify, using a .csv dataset >3GB each, therefore I am looking for an efficient tool, that would be also enough easy to read. I wonder if there is something better that `case_when` and tried to use a `named vector` based on answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62359465/more-efficient-way-for-modifying-values-across-multiple-lines-with-dplyr).

But, I have two questions:

- First, how to make `named vector` to work on my example?
- Second, will the `named_vector` be faster then `case_when`? (does it worth it?)

Here is my dummy example and expected output:

```
 # Create data table
 dd <- data.table(id = 1:5,
                   cell = c('k8', 
                            'k9',
                            "w7",
                            'w7',
                            'k3'))
  # create a named vector
  v1 <- setNames(c('k8', 
                   'k9',
                   'w7',
                   'k3'), as.character(1:4))
  
  # Classify the data using `case_when`
  dd %>%  
    mutate(nb = case_when(
      cell == "k8" ~ "1",
      cell == "k9" ~ "2",
      cell == "w7" ~ "3",
      cell == "k3" ~ "4"))
      
  # Classify the data using `named vector` - not working!
  dd %>%
    mutate(cell, ~ v1[as.character(.x)])
  

# Expected output: note that `nb` is a character, not numeric!



  id cell nb
1:  1   k8  1
2:  2   k9  2
3:  3   w7  3
4:  4   w7  3
5:  5   k3  4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to go the other way around:

```
dummy <- setNames( as.character(1:4), c('k8','k9','w7','k3'))
dd[, nb := dummy[cell]]

dd
#    id cell nb
# 1:  1   k8  1
# 2:  2   k9  2
# 3:  3   w7  3
# 4:  4   w7  3
# 5:  5   k3  4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following `data.table` option using `on =`  option

```
> dd[stack(v1), nb := ind, on = .(cell = values)][]
   id cell nb
1:  1   k8  1
2:  2   k9  2
3:  3   w7  3
4:  4   w7  3
5:  5   k3  4
```